# ListView WPF c автоизменением ширины колонок при увеличении размеров окна

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Доброго времени суток. В моем приложении на стороне сервера есть ListView который занимает весь экран. в нем всего два столбца. Нужно чтобы столбцы всегда делили пространство по ширине поровну при изменении размеров экрана. Т.е. не зависимо от содержимого заголовка, заголовок всегда расположен по центру столбца и его ширина половина ширины окна. Выставлять фиксированную `GridViewColumn Width=""` не подходит, если `Auto` то ширина подстраивается под длину заголовка, а мне надо чтобы длина заголовка всегда была равной половине длине экрана.

Заранее всем спасибо!!!.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="35" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ListHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="55" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Crimson" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


        <ListView Name="TicketItems"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Background="{Binding Path=ColorBackground,
                                   Mode=OneWay}">

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListHeaderStyle}">
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Номер билета">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=TicketName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Касса">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=CashierName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Ребят сделал как тут http://lazycowprojects.tumblr.com/post/7063214400/wpf-c-listview-column-width-auto   Но появилась паразитная колка справа. На скрине п о ссылке видно

Comment: Делаем как тут замечательная вешьhttp://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25058/ListView-Layout-Manager

Comment: попробуй поставить * вместо Auto, в UWP помогает обычно

Comment: Прошел почти год с момента задания вопроса, думаю, что ответ был найден :)